# Can't understand a Method in C# in unity

Tags: c#, methods, unity-game-engine

I tried nothing yet.

So i was working on a game tutorial, and the guy used a method like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D target)
    {
```

- I do not see any where in the class we are at that calls this method...
- I do not see any where in my other classes who calls this method,

and yet it works when we do stuff like:

```
if (target.tag == "BackGround")
```

So my question is how this method works, how do i know what gives and how this type: Collider2D, and its variable: target?

Comment: *I tried nothing yet.* that's not a great way to kick off

Answer (score 2):

You can call OnTiggerEnter because it inherits from MonoBehaviour.
You have 2 collider types, 3D and 2D. And also you have OnTriggerEnter and OnCollisionEnter. When you say OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) it will check for the "other" collider type and act as it should.
If you say other.tag or other.name, "other" is your GameObject.

Documentation here :http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html
Hope it helped.